# Should I use Cucumber for an AngularJS single page application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cucumber, angularjs-e2e

I'm fairly new to both Cucumber and Angular. I have a rails application that is a single page application. Should I bother with Cucumber or should I just use AngularJS's e2e testing?

Any insight, comparison and past experience is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

We use a combination of Cucumber and Jasmine for our Angular application.

Months ago when I initially tried to get Angular's e2e testing framework running , the documentation was pretty limited so we opted for Cucumber - Selenium for the UI tests.

I believe with Angular's e2e framework you can mock calls to backend but if you want to do actual integration testing using Cucumber + Selenium is a decent option.

Comment: is Cucumber still the best option for e2e with angular?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [Cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js).

If  you're looking for a more comprehensive example using Protractor checkout this [angular-cucumber-example](https://github.com/whyvez/angular-cucumber-example).

Comment: This is a top search result, too, so the options appears popular.